# How to get object clicked by mouse but not when it is behind the button that was clickecked?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use this code to get an object clicked by the mouse

```
void Update() {
  if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = camera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit)) {
      Transform objectHit = hit.transform;
    }
  }
}
```

This code works even when I click the button and do not want to click an object that is behind the button. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 2):

There is simple solution in Unity. You need to use this function, it returns true if mouse pointer is over UI element, like button.

```
EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject()
```

Like this:

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {
        // UI wasn't clicked
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could instead implement the [`IPointerDownHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) and [`IPointerUpHandler`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.html) interfaces on the target object you want to click on like

```c#
public class Interactable3D : MonoBehaviour, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        Debug.Log(name + "Game Object Click in Progress");
    }

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        // Whatever should happen
    }
}
```

> Use the `IPointerUpHandler` Interface to handle pointer up input using `OnPointerUp` callbacks. Ensure an `EventSystem` exists in the Scene to allow click detection. For click detection on non-UI GameObjects, ensure a `PhysicsRaycaster` is attached to the `Camera`.

And ofcourse it still requires to have a `Collider` attached.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Layer Mask, you can assign the gameobject that you don't want to click to the ignore raycast layer.

you can read more about that here : [Unity Documentation - LayerMask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.html)